# Error attaching device to DPDK

Tags: networking, drivers

Error attaching device to DPDK while adding interfaces to OVS bond on Ubuntu.

- Ubuntu 20.04.3
- DPDK 19.11.10
- OVS 2.13.3
- NICs Intel x710 (fw 7.10)

Command:

```
ovs-vsctl add-bond ovsbr0 bond0  ens2f0 ens2f1 ens3f0 ens3f1 \
   -- set Interface ens2f0 type=dpdk  "options:dpdk-devargs=0000:5e:00.0" \
   -- set Interface ens2f1 type=dpdk  "options:dpdk-devargs=0000:5e:00.1" \
   -- set Interface ens3f0 type=dpdk  "options:dpdk-devargs=0000:d8:00.0" \
   -- set Interface ens3f1 type=dpdk  "options:dpdk-devargs=0000:d8:00.1"
```

Output:

```
ovs-vsctl: Error detected while setting up 'ens2f0': Error attaching device '0000:5e:00.0' to DPDK.  See ovs-vswitchd log for details.
ovs-vsctl: Error detected while setting up 'ens2f1': Error attaching device '0000:5e:00.1' to DPDK.  See ovs-vswitchd log for details.
ovs-vsctl: Error detected while setting up 'ens3f0': Error attaching device '0000:d8:00.0' to DPDK.  See ovs-vswitchd log for details.
ovs-vsctl: Error detected while setting up 'ens3f1': Error attaching device '0000:d8:00.1' to DPDK.  See ovs-vswitchd log for details.
ovs-vsctl: The default log directory is "/var/log/openvswitch".
```

/var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.log

```
2022-01-03T16:00:05.776Z|00083|dpdk|ERR|EAL: Driver cannot attach the device (0000:d8:00.1)
2022-01-03T16:00:05.776Z|00084|dpdk|ERR|EAL: Failed to attach device on primary process
2022-01-03T16:00:05.776Z|00085|netdev_dpdk|WARN|Error attaching device '0000:d8:00.1' to DPDK
2022-01-03T16:00:05.776Z|00086|netdev|WARN|ens3f1: could not set configuration (Invalid argument)
2022-01-03T16:00:05.776Z|00087|dpdk|ERR|Invalid port_id=32
```

VT-d support is enabled:

```
cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-91-generic root=UUID=2849776f-b167-447f-a5d1-ea4b5c831c35 ro iommu=pt intel_iommu=on
```

I use **vfio-pci** driver.

DMAR:

```
$ grep -i dmar charlie-dmesg2.yml | grep -i iommu
[    0.703534] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
[    1.353766] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 12 under DRHD base  0xc5ffc000 IOMMU 6
[    1.353767] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 11 under DRHD base  0xb87fc000 IOMMU 5
[    1.353768] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 10 under DRHD base  0xaaffc000 IOMMU 4
[    1.353770] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 18 under DRHD base  0xfbffc000 IOMMU 3
[    1.353771] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 17 under DRHD base  0xee7fc000 IOMMU 2
[    1.353773] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 16 under DRHD base  0xe0ffc000 IOMMU 1
[    1.353774] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 15 under DRHD base  0xd37fc000 IOMMU 0
[    1.353775] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 8 under DRHD base  0x9d7fc000 IOMMU 7
[    1.353777] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 9 under DRHD base  0x9d7fc000 IOMMU 7
```

The issue occurs in case of Ubuntu autoinstallation only. Ubuntu installed manually works fine.

Comment: can you please share the driver with which you are binding to DPDK. Is it uio_pci_generic, igb_uio or vfio-pci?  If it is vfio-pci can you please check DMAR for iommu from dmesg?

Comment: I use vfio-pci:  

`$ grep -i dmar charlie-dmesg2.yml | grep -i iommu
[    0.703534] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
[    1.353766] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 12 under DRHD base  0xc5ffc000 IOMMU 6
[    1.353767] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 11 under DRHD base  0xb87fc000 IOMMU 5
[    1.353768] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 10 under DRHD base  0xaaffc000 IOMMU 4
[    1.353770] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 18 under DRHD base  0xfbffc000 IOMMU 3
[    1.353771] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 17 under DRHD base  0xee7fc000 IOMMU 2
[    1.353773] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 16 under DRHD base  0xe0ffc000 IOMMU 1
[...]`

Comment: thanks for the response, as per the dmesg DMAR logs IOMMU is enabled on your machine. can you check in dmesg once the bind fails if its log ` Cannot bind to driver vfio-pci`? If yes, then vfio-pci bind with default iommu is failing. Please try `echo 1 > /sys/module/vfio/parameters/enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode` and share.

Comment: @VipinVarghese thank you for helping me. The dmesg output doesn't contain any messages about vfio-pci. Just in case, I tried the command you sent. No luck.

Comment: very interesting issue, are you using Intel x86 or and x86 processor? If it is AMD `amd_iommu=pt` is to be used. But since you mentioned manual installation works, I would like to look more into this behaviour will it be possible for a debug?

Comment: My colleague suggested me to install the package **libdpdk-dev**. It pulls the whole bunch of dependencies, but finally solves the issue. Good luck!

Comment: as per the officeal package information https://packages.debian.org/sid/libdpdk-dev, it implies these are `DPDK libraries compiled with SSE as minimum`. Hence I am unable to understand how manual DPDK 19.11.10 is used to solve the issue. SOmething is not rigyt.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `pci=realloc=on` to kernel boot parameters solved the issue for me